# How to convolve array of arrays with a mask in Python?

Tags: python, mask, convolution

Given a t1xt2xn array and a m1xm2 mask, how to obtain the t1xt2xn array where the n-dim arrays are convolved with the mask?

The function scipy.signal.convolve is not able to handle this because it only accept inputs with same number of dimensions.

Example with the "same" logic:

```
in1 =
[[[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]],
[[9,10,11],[12,13,14],[15,16,17]],
[[18,19,20],[21,22,23],[24,25,26]]]

in2 =
[[0,1,0],
[0,1,0],
[0,1,0]]

output =
[[[0,0,0],[15,17,19],[0,0,0]],
[[0,0,0],[36,39,42],[0,0,0]],
[[0,0,0],[33,35,37],[0,0,0]]]
```

Comment: Does your m1xm2 mask's shape is (t1, t2)?

Comment: @frist Not necessarily: m1<= t1 and m2<=t2

Comment: So how should it work? Can you give us example input of t1xt2xn, m1xm2 and expected result of convolving?

Comment: @frist Thanks, I've added the example. It is for the case (m1=t1, m2=t2) because it's easier to visualise but the principle is the same for the common convolution, I just want element-wise sums/products on the last dimension.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very sorry but I haven't strong math background, so my answer could be wrong. Anyway, if you need to use mask for selecting you should convert it to bool type. For example:

```
in1 = np.array([[[0,1,2],    [3,4,5],    [6,7,8]],
                [[9,10,11],  [12,13,14], [15,16,17]],
                [[18,19,20], [21,22,23], [24,25,26]]])

in2 = np.array([[0, 1, 0],
                [0, 1, 0],
                [0, 1, 0]])

mask = in2.astype(bool)

print(in1[mask])
# [[ 3  4  5]
#  [12 13 14]
#  [21 22 23]]

in3 = np.zeros(in1.shape)

in3[mask] = np.convolve(in1[mask].ravel(), in2.ravel(), 'same').reshape(mask.shape)

print(in3)

# [[[  0.   0.   0.]
#   [ 15.  17.  19.]
#   [  0.   0.   0.]]
# 
#  [[  0.   0.   0.]
#   [ 36.  39.  42.]
#   [  0.   0.   0.]]
# 
#  [[  0.   0.   0.]
#   [ 33.  35.  37.]
#   [  0.   0.   0.]]]
```

I'm not very sure about last part, especially about reshaping but I hope you get an idea.